# Copy all metadata (Chapters and...) from one wav file to another

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, wav

How can I copy all the metadata (containing all chapters info) from one wav file to another?
I tried so many different methods, but so far none of them worked.
for example this wont work

```
ffmpeg -i in0.wav -i in1.wav -map 1 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a out.wav
```

I want to have all the extra information inside the first wav file in second wav file.

after that what I want to do as well is some have combine all this with conversation from mp3 to wav in one command, is it possible?